# children.clientWidth getting property from window, not from element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This odd thing is happening and can't seem to resolve it.

In order to adjust a ul element on the screen, I need to get its children width.

I am attempting to do that with function below, but instead of fetching the property from the element li, it's getting it somewhere else. Not sure where from though. It's not exactly the window, but close. When I resize the window the figure changes, but always not quite the window width.

As you can see in the code, I am verifying that it gets the correct element.

```
function adjustTabs() {
   var myUl = document.getElementById("tabname");

   for (var i = 0; i < myUl.children.length; i++) {
     console.log(i); // correct output
     console.log(myUl.children[i]); //correct output 
     console.log('width',myUl.children[i].clientWidth); // wrong output
   }
};

$(function () {
    adjustTabs();
});
```

And here is partial output of an instance of the second console.log above, ie,

> console.log(myUl.children[i]);

```
li.tab
    accessKey: ""
    accessKeyLabel: ""
    attributes: NamedNodeMap [ class="tab" ]
    baseURI: "http://localhost/marques-voiture/BMW"
    childElementCount: 3
    childNodes: NodeList [ #text, input#tab1, #text, … ]
    children: HTMLCollection [ input#tab1, label, div#tab-content1.content ]
    classList: DOMTokenList [ "tab" ]
    className: "tab"
    clientHeight: 29
    clientLeft: 0
    clientTop: 0
    clientWidth: 138
    contentEditable: "inherit"
    contextMenu: null
    .......
```

So, for this one it should output 138, but it outputs something like 1500. It outputs the same figure ( 1500 in the case ) for all instances of the li element.

Any ideas

Thanks